# How to update entity in database with relationship in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I would like to update entity in database with One-To-Many relationship.

Director model:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Director {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "director")
    private Set<Movie> movies;

`}
```

Movie model:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "director_id")
    private Director director;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private MovieGenre genre;

    private String description;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "actorsMovies",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id"))
    private Set<Actor> stars;

    private Integer release;

}
```

controller class:

```
   @PostMapping("{directorId}/addMovie/{movieId}")
    public String addMovieToDirector(
            @PathVariable("directorId") Long directorId,
            @PathVariable("movieId") Long movieId) {

        log.info("directorId: " + directorId);
        log.info("movieId: " + movieId);

       return directorService.addMovieToDirector(directorId, movieId);
    }
```

service class:

```
    @Override
    public String addMovieToDirector(Long directorId, Long movieId) {

        if (directorRepository.findById(directorId).isPresent() && movieRepository.findById(movieId).isPresent()) {
            Director director = directorRepository.findById(directorId).get();
            Set<Movie> movies = director.getMovies();
            Movie movie = movieRepository.findById(movieId).get();
            if (movies.contains(movie)) return "contains";
            movies.add(movie);
            director.setMovies(movies);
            directorRepository.save(director);
            return "added";
        }
        return "error";
    }
```

I am using JpaRepository and when i try to update movies in director entity i receive "added" message but nothing happens. When i try to update firstname for example then everything works fine. What is the issue?

Does anyone have an idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public String addMovieToDirector(Long directorId, Long movieId) {
    Optional<Director> optinalDirector = directorRepository.findById(directorId);
    Optional<Movie> optionalMovie = movieRepository.findById(movieId);
        if (optinalDirector.isPresent() && optionalMovie.isPresent()) {
            if (optionalMovie.get().getDirector().equals(optinalDirector.get()) { 
               return "contains";
            }
            optionalMovie.get().setDirector(optinalDirector.get())
            movieRepository.save(optionalMovie.get());
            return "added";
        }else
          return "error";
}
```